# C: Convert array to RGB image

Tags: c, arrays, image

In C, I have a 1D array of unsigned chars (ie, between 0 to 255) of length `3*DIM*DIM` which represents a `DIM*DIM` pixel image, where the first 3 pixels are the RGB levels of the first pixel, the second 3 pixels are the RGB levels of the second pixel, etc. I would like to save it as a PNG image. What is the easiest, most lightweight method of doing this conversion?

Obviously OpenGL can read and display images of this form (GLUT_RGB), but `DIM` is larger than the dimensions of my monitor screen, so simply displaying the image and taking a screenshot is not an option.

At the moment, I have been doing the conversion by simply saving the array to a CSV file, loading it in Mathematica, and then exporting it as a PNG, but this is very slow (~8 minutes for a single 7000*7000 pixel image).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many excellent third party libraries you can use to convert an array of pixel-data to a picture.

- [libPNG](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/) is a long standing standard library for png images.
- [LodePNG](http://lodev.org/lodepng/) also seems like a good candidate.
- Finally, [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) is a great library that supports many different image formats.

All these support C, and are relatively easy to use.

Comment: LodePNG seems like the perfect method; it's just a single .h file! Thanks for the reference. I also saw libPNG before writing this question, but it seemed like overkill, so LodePNG it is.